# Algorithm for finding possible ways of simple, multiple encryption with the alphabet

Tags: c++, algorithm, encryption

When using a simple encryption method in which the letters are replaced by the indexing numbers of the alphabet, there are multiple ways of decrypting them, ex. ABOR is 121518 but 121518 could also be AYEAH or LAER.

Well I need an algorithm to calculate how many possible ways there are for a given number to decrypt the message via the described method (ex 1225 has 5 - ABBE, AVE, ABY, LBE, LY ).

Help me if you want to.

Comment: It's not encrypt. It's just encode.

Comment: Have you tried prefixing the numbers 1...9 with a zero, so that 'A' corresponds to 01?  This would make decoding easier since every letter is represented by a pair of digits rather than 1 or two digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it recursively.

The total number of ways of encoding the first n digits is (the number of ways of encoding the first n-1 digits if the last digit is 1 <= d <= 9) + (the number of ways of encoding the first n-2 digits if the last two digits are 10 <= dd <=26).

Cache results or use dynamic programming to prevent exponential explosion. The technique is very similar to calculating Fibonacci numbers.

Here's how you could do it in Python, to demonstrate the principle:

```
# s is of form [1-9][0-9]*
s = '121518'
a=1 # Cache of f(i - 2)
b=1 # Cache of f(i - 1)
for i in range(1, len(s)):
   a, b = b, a * (10 <= int(s[i - 1: i + 1]) <= 26) + b * (s[i] != '0')
print b
```

You could do it in a similar way in C++, but as this seems to be a homework / learning exercise, I hope you don't mind that I'll leave you to work out the details in C++.

Comment: In fact, this should be fairly linear in run time with dynamic programming.

Comment: The run time *is* linear, not just "fairly linear". :-) (Assuming you don't do something stupid like traversing the string on each iteration, for recalculating length or finding s[i].)

Comment: Thanks a lot but i can't really understand what exactly you're doing in the longest line - is that <= smaller or equal sign ? and the multiplying of b with the statement (s[i] != '0') ?

Comment: @ggg: The first bit is (10 <= dd <= 26), i.e. dd must be between 10 and 26. The second is (1 <= d <= 9), but I wrote it as (d != 0) instead. The multiplication is like 'if' because true converts to 1 and false to 0. You don't have to write it so compressed if you don't want. You can write `if (....) { total += a; }` etc... if you want to be more explicit.